# How to install PowerCLI permanently on a computer with no internet

Tags: powershell, vmware, powercli

I downloaded the PowerCLI from VMware's website.

`https://my.vmware.com/web/vmware/details?downloadGroup=PCLI650R1&productId=614`

Once downloaded their is an executable PowerCLI.exe. If I run this executable I get a terminal (that is not cmd/powershell) that pops up with all the PowerCLI commands available.

The problem is when I open a real PowerShell terminal, these commands disappear and are unavailable.

While looking at the folder I downloaded from VMware's website I noticed a script called "initizilize_environment.ps1", after I run this script (its about 5-10 mins)I get access to the PowerCLI commands again. The problem is I loose access to these commands once the PowerShell terminal is closed. This is a big problem as I'm trying to automate the virtual environment and having to wait 5-10 minutes defeats the point.

I would install the PowerCLI via the following, but due to security restrictions the machine cannot have access to the internet.
`Save-Module -Name VMware.PowerCLI -Path <path>`

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: You are not using the current version of [PowerCLI](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/VMware.PowerCLI/11.1.0.11289667) there are more options to install current versions of PowerCLI

Answer (score -1):

Save it via an internet connected device.

Then copy it from that systems module folder...

https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2013/05/18/powertip-find-the-path-to-a-powershell-module

Then copy the module folder to the non-connected host manually, via USB/CD/DVD, whatever you are allowed to use.

- Raymond follow up -
  Consolidating my follow-up comments.

The link as I said was only a pointer to look for the module location.

As for the down vote on this, no I don't underestimate, as I've done this as well as other 3rdP modules. Even if you used the VMware docs on the topic, you'd want to use the link, because of all the manual install / find / copy and paste steps they give you, the would be an unecessary operation to this Q&A.

As it talks to removing old versions, and other steps.

Yet, ultimately, it's still a install on a connected system and copy paste, and a few other manual steps on the disconnected system.

But since you don't think it's improper and that links will go away, Then OK:

> Accessing the PowerCLI Modules
>
> https://blogs.vmware.com/PowerCLI/2018/01/powercli-offline-installation-walkthrough.html
>
> Online System with PowerShell 5.x:
>
> •Open PowerShell
>
> •Use the
>   ‘Save-Module’ cmdlet to download the PowerCLI modules locally.
>
> Example:
>
> Save-Module -Name VMware.PowerCLI -Path C:\Path\To\Destination\Folder
>
> •If requested, update the NuGet provider
>
> •If requested, trust the
>
> ‘Untrusted repository’ that is named PSGallery Note: This is a local
>   system trust, not something that has something to do with an SSL
>   certificate
>
> •Copy those downloaded module folders to a location that can be made
>   accessible to the offline system.
>
> Example: USB Flash Drive, Internal
>   File Share, etc.
>
> Adding PowerCLI to the Offline System
>
> It’s now time to put the PowerCLI modules on to the offline system. To
>   take advantage of the magic that is module auto-loading, we’ll want to
>   copy and paste those downloaded folders in one of the locations listed
>   in the PSModulePath variable.
>
> By default, the PSModulePath variable contains the following
>   directories: 
>   •$home\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\Modules
>
> •$pshome\Modules
>
> That’s it! Open a PowerShell session and start using your PowerCLI
>   commands as you did before!